# What does "Please enter the same address in both email address fields" mean for steam

Tags: steam

I cannot make a Steam account because Steam keeps saying this:

> Please enter the same address in both email address fields

Answer (score 11):

It means the two email addresses do not match.

Type it in slowly and try again.

[image]

Comment: I thought it meant home adress

Comment: @Bobbylee If this answer worked for you, please press the green checkmark beneath the answer's votes in order to accept it. Accepted answers are a reliable way to show to new visitors to the question what worked for you.